# Integrating Planck's relation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, frequency

By Planck relation, we know that an energy of a single photon is $E = hf$.

If we are given EM-waves with interval of frequency $f_1$ to $f_2$, does integrating from
$\int_{f1}^{f2} Edf$ $=\int_{f1}^{f2} (hf) df$ give us anything useful?

I'm thinking that it would give us the $n$ integer multiple of range of possible energy received but I'm not too sure.

Comment: If you insert some photon probability density, you obtain the average photon energy. Currently you have the average photon energy times the frequency interval width, under the assumption of equidistribution in the frequency range. Not sure what one does with that physically.

Comment: @kriceli I would like to know more about what you just said. After we plug in the photon probability density, what does the average photon energy mean since photons are quantized? Can we have a probability density with equal probability to all the frequencies?